# Changing display property to block with img onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have an "error" element that is hidden by default on the page. I have an overlay popup that appears on page load (which is working fine) and I have a 'dismiss' button within this overlay that hides the overlay (again, this is working). However, I also want it to change the display property of the "error" element on the page from none to block when clicking on the dismiss button inside my overlay.

The "error" element on the page...

```
<div id="error_dismissed" style="display:none;">you dismissed it man!!!!!!</div>
```

The dismiss button (shows on overlay popup)...

```
<img onclick="var bi=document.getElementById('main'); if (bi) set_opacity(bi,1.0); document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('error_dismissed').style.display='block';" src="dismiss.png" />
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you put all that JavaScript in the HTML property? Aside from making terribly hard to read, it's nearly impossible to debug. Your code works for the part that changes the property to `block`, so most likely there is an error in the script before that which is preventing it from reaching that line. Move the script to a function so you can debug it.

Comment: Using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code - it's basically `eval`. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m5cmvkrk/

Answer (score 1):

Putting all that JavaScript in the HTML property makes it terribly hard to read and debug. Your code works for the part that changes the property to `block`, so most likely there is an error in the script before that which is preventing it from reaching that line. Move the script to a function so you can debug it.

Here is a demo of your code working. I didn't change anything except adding a `<div id="overlay"></div>` which is referenced in the code:

```html
<div id="error_dismissed" style="display:none;">you dismissed it man!!!!!!</div>
<img onclick="var bi=document.getElementById('main'); if (bi) set_opacity(bi,1.0); document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('error_dismissed').style.display='block';" src="dismiss.png" />
<div id="overlay"></div>
```